# How can I get the total number of characters in the given string that are digits?

Tags: python, string

How do I count the number of digits in a string?

For example:

```
>>> count_digits("ABC123")
```

should return 3.

Comment: user1718467, Based on your comment to @A. R. S. I've amended your question. If you disapprove let me know in the comments

Comment: Seriously, couldn't you type the same thing into Google?

Comment: To the guy who posted and then removed the solution that used `.translate()`... I thought that was nuts but it turns out it's an order of magnitude quicker than any other solution posted. A real surprise.

Comment: @RobCowie The problem is, that it works the wrong way around, it stripped the digits, which is why I removed it again.

Comment: This question is not too localized.

Answer (score 18):

Try this:

```
len("ABC123")
```

Simple as pie. It might behoof you to read the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#len) regarding `len`.

---

**Edit** Your original post was ambiguous about whether you wanted the total length or the number of digits. Seeing as you want the latter, I should tell you that there are a million ways of doing it, here are three:

```
s = "abc123"

print len([c for c in s if c.isdigit()])
print [c.isdigit() for c in s].count(True)
print sum(c.isdigit() for c in s)  # I'd say this would be the best approach
```

Comment: I only need the number of digits in the string.

Comment: no need of `count(True)`, just sum the list : `sum(c.isdigit() for c in s)`

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Yes, just wanted to show that there are multiple ways of going about it - but you're right.

Answer (score 6):

I suspect you want to count the number of digits in a string

```
s = 'ABC123'
len([c for c in s if c.isdigit()]) ## 3
```

Or perhaps you want to count the number of adjacent digits

```
s = 'ABC123DEF456'
import re
len(re.findall('[\d]+', s)) ## 2
```

Comment: Thanks for the regex solution! It's more powerful and can be extended to identifying money, for instance.

Answer (score 4):

```
sum(1 for c in "ABC123" if c.isdigit())
```

Comment: or simply `sum(c.isdigit() for c in "ABC123")`
`