# How to reserve at least 3 digits for a float number

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, numpy

Here is an example of a dataframe in previous research:

[image]

It seems that the output number is in the format of at least 3 digits (e.g 1070, 0.073). For now, I can only transform the original float number into the data with same format after the dot

```
str("{:.3f}".format(df['values'])
```

Therefore, how to transform the original data into the table as the figure above?

Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: I'd want to challenge your assumption. The values are not *shown* as 3-digits-at least, they represent the actual *measurement accuracy*. If you display a measured value `7.5` as `7.50`, you are implying more accuracy than present in your data.

Comment: For example, the feature "Sr" and "Lu" both can be corrected to "0.xxx". But the table is shown in 5.03 and 0.004, both in 3 digits.

Comment: But `7.5` and `4.3` are *not* shown as `7.50` and `4.30`.

Comment: Apart from the coding problem - is there any rationale for a different accuracy for different chemical elements?

Comment: The measured method was the same for different species. I doubt the detection limits might differ in species.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add zeroes at the end of a float and still keep it a float. You must change its representation to a *string* first. Then, count the number of digits and add zeroes at the end. Don't forget to add a `.` if the number initially did not contain decimals.

That leads to the following small function. To count digits, I use a regular expression so it needs `re`.

```
import re

def padZero(value, target_width):
    result = str(value)
    numdigits = len(re.findall(r"\d", result))
    if numdigits < target_width:
        if value == int(value):
            result += '.'
        while numdigits < target_width:
            numdigits += 1
            result += '0'
    return result
```

This general algorithm can be rewritten in a more Pythonic way as:

```
def padZero(value, target_width):
    result = str(value)
    if 'e' not in result:
        numdigits = sum(n.isdigit() for n in result)
        if numdigits < target_width:
            if value == int(value):
                result += '.'
            result += '0'*(target_width - numdigits)
    return result
```

using the neat `sum` trick in the answer and comment of https://stackoverflow.com/a/12717649, which nicely removes the necessity of `re`, and a string multiplier to add the correct number of `0`s.

Adding an explicit check for an `e` in the string representation prevents an odd outcome for very large or very small numbers such as `1e20`, in which case the unchanged string is returned.

```
 >>> print padZero(0.01, 4)
 0.010
 >>> print padZero(15,3)
 15.0
```